# What is billing charges of batch request in firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have two questions regarding the Firestore.

1. If we update a document and nothing updates in row or effected row 0, will it charge?
2. Does batch update charge for one document or for all affected documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. if we update a document if nothing updates in row or effected row 0,Will it charge .

If you are querying your database to find a specific document and you don't make any change, you are charged with a single read operation. In this case, you won't be charged for any write operations. Regarding the one read operation, this is an **exception**, so if you have a query that returns **no documents** you are billed for a single document read. This means every query incurs a cost of **at least one** document read, no matter the results.

> 2. does batch update charge for one document or all affected documents.

You'll be charged for all affected documents.

As a conclusion, you'll be billed for any documents matched by a query. Please see official documentation regarding [Firestore pricing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing).

Comment: I also always recommend Todd's video on Firestore pricing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NegFl9p_sE&t=6s&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=4